# I believe I was hacked over night

Tags: command-line, ssh, sudo, history, hacking

I believe I was hacked last night. I am a little bit new to the Linux world so I don't know if this is normal or not, but there were a lot of random things in my command line history. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kQJgvxEoQPvww4QWhfR0BEdioyVEz9BR/view?usp=sharing) a Google Drive can be found with the history of my command line. Lines 814 and further were not ran by me. I believe a lot of what he wrote is some sort of HTML code.

Comment: Is it possible that you viewed the "page source" of an HTML page and then mistakenly copied and pasted it into a terminal window by accident?

Comment: " I am a little bit new to the Linux world" then what makes you believe you can claim "I believe I was hacked last night."? Where is the router log that shows someone entered your system?  Just an FYI: your history is what YOU inserted into the system. Someone who hacked your system would not be visible in the history of your user. He's be user root.  You did not get hacked.

Answer (score 3):

Is [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/464585/447865) the post you were looking at last night?? I am not a hacker, but I can say that you have not been hacked. You just accidently copied the HTML code of the post. In the image below, you can see that you have copied the same lines.
A final message.

1. Don`t panic and think logically what these lines mean.
2. Beware what you copy from the internet before running them in the terminal. Luckily, this were just few HTML lines. What if they were some other form of command that you didn`t want to execute but you copied them and they ran in the terminal. This may even sometimes lead to data deletion, package removal or even break your OS.
   See images below where you can see how I found the post you were looking at.
   [image: See the lines here]
   From this, I can tell you were looking at **stackexchange - Topic - Error:- umount:target is busy.** [image: And see the lines here]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I looked at my browser history and I have never been on stack exchange. I also am not at the stage in my Linux course where I learn about umount. Edit: The problem was I had a malware which allowed people who had my public IP address have full access to my command line.